# How to inspect the attributes of a Struct/Mutable Struct in Julia

Tags: julia

I have a struct defined as follows:

```
julia> struct test
           test1::Int64
           test2::Float64
       end
```

I want to be able to see the names of the attributes in the struct as well as the type. What is the most straight forward way to do this? I know I can do:

```
julia> t = test(1,1.0)
test(1, 1.0)

julia> fieldnames(typeof(t))
(:test1, :test2)
```

but I would like to see the attribute name and type together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `fieldtypes(typeof(t))`

```
julia> DataFrame(name=[fieldnames(typeof(t))...], type=[fieldtypes(typeof(t))...])
2×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ name   │ type     │
│     │ Symbol │ DataType │
├─────┼────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ test1  │ Int64    │
│ 2   │ test2  │ Float64  │
```

Regarding the other answer note that `dump` outputs always the entire data structure which is not good for fields having complex types. Try doing `dump` on a struct that has a `Dict` field to find out my point (or just try in the console) `dump(Dict())`.

Answer (score 3):

The most straight forward way to do this would be to use the `dump` method:

> help?> dump
> search: dump
>
> dump(x; maxdepth=8)
>
> Show every part of the representation of a value. The depth of the
> output is truncated   at maxdepth.

So in this case, it would show:

```
julia> dump(t)
test
  test1: Int64 1
  test2: Float64 1.0
```

See here for more details: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.dump